# iPhone Xr: Ringer volume sound loud for the first second then goes real quiet?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have checked sound and haptics, the phone settings the contacts settings, but still cant figure out why it changes volume during the ring tone. I use stock ringer tones.

Answer (score 3):

The lowering of alerts sounds is a feature of iOS. To disable the feature, go to 
Settings > Face ID & Passcode > Attention Aware Features and then toggle the setting off.